# invalid SHA1 signature file digest

Tags: jnlp

I have been trying to verify the Jar signing:

```
    jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs example.jar
```

I got the following problem:

```
jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for o
rg/apache/log4j/net/DefaultEvaluator.class
```

I got some suggestions about using `-digestalg SHA-1` but I do not know where I should put this statement!

I hope you can help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
jarsigner -keystore mykeystore -digestalg SHA1 jarfile alias
```

To verify:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs jarfile
```

Comment: This same solution works if you're getting the SHA-256 variant of the message the OP was getting.

Comment: this only works when the original jars are not signed already.

Answer (score 44):

This error can also happen when the jar is signed twice.

The solution was to 'unsign' the jar by deleting *.**SF**, *.**DSA**, *.**RSA** files from the jar's **META-INF** and then signing the jar again.

Comment: Confirmed, for me the problem was the jar being signed twice.

Comment: Was not enough in my case. Also had to delete "SHA" records in manifest file.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.  I had to change my ANT to version 1.8.3 and add DIGESTALG attribute:

```
<!-- VLS2014 ADDED digestalg="SHA1" -->
<signjar keystore="${security.keystore}"
         storepass="${security.storepass}"
         keypass="${security.keypass}"
         alias="${security.alias}"
         jar="${basedir}/temp/tj/${justfname}"
         signedjar="${real.signed.jar}"
     digestalg="SHA1"
        />

<delete file="${basedir}/temp/tj/${justfname}" />
</target>
```