# How to resolve invalid SHA1 signature when signing the Android app?

Tags: android

When I verify the signature of my application:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs testapp.apk
```

it gives me the error:

`jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for res/drawable-xhdpi/breadcrumb_grey_white.png`

How to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid SHA1 signature file digest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176166/invalid-sha1-signature-file-digest)

Answer (score 11):

make sure to delete the META_INF folder in the apk before signing it. 
Also, if you are using JDK 7, then include the the option -sigalg MD5withRSA when signing with the jarsigner along with -digestalg SHA1 mentioned by Andrejs

Comment: Caution: if you are trying to sign OSGi bundles remember META_INF/Manifest.mf has some required headers. removing META-INF folder will cause undesirable outcomes.

Answer (score 3):

**Ripped from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176166/invalid-sha1-signature-file-digest).**

Here is the solution:

```
jarsigner -keystore mykeystore -digestalg SHA1 jarfile alias
```

To verify:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs jarfile
```

Comment: When i verify with JDK 1.6.0 it is working perfectly but when i try with JDK 1.7.0 it is coming invalid SHA1 signature file digest for res/drawable-xhdpi/breadcrumb_grey_white.png. Why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps you need to re-sign it with 1.7.0, and verify with the same version as well?

Comment: what is the procedure to resign with 1.7.0?

Comment: I don't know about resigning, but you might try sign unsigned *jar*.